# How do I mark enemies?

Tags: gunfire-reborn

There's an inscription for the crossbow that says

[image]

> When the scope is on, you can mark 2 enemies through aiming so shooting anywhere will deal Crit DMG to marked enemies

However, I couldn't get this to work - I was only getting crits from headshots as usual.  **How do I "mark" an enemy?**